# Is this possible to set hamburger menu below of Toolbar in NavigationView?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, navigationview, material-components, material-components-android

i want to change menu icon below of toolbar. Is this possible to change the icon position.
Thanks in advance

[[image: please find the image [1]]

Comment: Can you give an example of what do you mean?

Comment: Where is the XML for your toolbar?

Comment: i want to display navigation Drawer menu icon below of toolbar. is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **`app:buttonGravity`** attribute to change the gravity of the buttons in the `Toolbar` and use a custom height.

Something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
    android:layout_height="...dp"
    app:buttonGravity="center_vertical"
    ../>
```

[image]

It can work also with the `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`.